# winnovative html to pdf converter not finding CSS when base url is a network share

Tags: winnovative

I am having an issue using Winnovatives HTML to pdf converter.

When the base url is a local path e.g C:\path\to\base, the converter resolves the files just fine.

however, in scenarios where the base url points to a server e.g
\\server\share\path\to\base, winnovative fails to find the css and generates a non formatted file.

Comment: NVM, Turns out you gotta use File://server/path/to/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it always needs a Drive:\ format path, and not a \server\share UNC path.

for remote files, you have to use File://server/share/path/to/file